# Creating Debian Package from Python Package using stdeb

Tags: python, debian, package

Having a folder of python project, containing the following common things:

-.py file which runs main () from `__init__`.py

-setup.py file with all the information needed for stdeb

-readme.txt file

-folder with `__init__`.py file

I've successfully installed the package via "`python setup.py install`" and test it using "`import run; run.main()`". All worked fine until that moment.

Then I'd like to transform my python package into debian one using stdeb library.

Use following command from the project folder "`python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb`"

Gives me the following traceback:

```
running bdist_deb
running sdist_dsc
running egg_info
writing run.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to run.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to run.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to run.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'run.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'run.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running sdist
running check
creating run-0.0.1
creating run-0.0.1/run
creating run-0.0.1/run.egg-info
copying files to run-0.0.1...
copying README.txt -> run-0.0.1
copying setup.py -> run-0.0.1
copying run/__init__.py -> run-0.0.1/run
copying run.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> run-0.0.1/run.egg-info
copying run.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> run-0.0.1/run.egg-info
copying run.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> run-0.0.1/run.egg-info
copying run.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> run-0.0.1/run.egg-info
copying run.egg-info/top_level.txt -> run-0.0.1/run.egg-info
Writing run-0.0.1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'run-0.0.1' (and everything under it)
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What in this case could cause the error "error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" and how can I deal with that?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the article which I founded here: http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-debian-packages-w-stdeb.html